# How to listen Android hardware back button in ionic

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I try to listen android hardware back button,but it is no effect.

main code:

```
.run(['$ionicPlatform','$ionicHistory',function($ionicPlatform,$ionicHistory) {
     $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
                          if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                          cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
                          }
                          if(window.StatusBar) {
                          StatusBar.styleDefault();
                          }
                          });
     $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         $ionicHistory.nextViewOptions({
             disableAnimate: true
        });
        $ionicHistory.viewHistory().backView.go();
         return false;
       }, 100);
     }])
```

My running environment is mobile browser.Android version 4.4.2

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: I'm no longer using this as it was unreliable. Additionally, in the latest Ionic release, app.ts is now app.component.ts.

For Ionic 2, check out my blog post on how to fix this.  Should also work for Ionic 1, as it's only calling a cordova listener:

http://www.codingandclimbing.co.uk/blog/ionic-2-android-back-button-13

and here's the actual post info:

**In your app.ts, do the following to get the back button working as expected (mostly!):**

```
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.registerBackButtonListener();
    });
  }

  registerBackButtonListener() {
    document.addEventListener('backbutton', () => {
      var nav = this.getNav();
      if (nav.canGoBack()) {
        nav.pop();
      }
      else {
        this.confirmExitApp(nav);
      }
    });
  }


confirmExitApp(nav) {
    let confirm = Alert.create({
      title: 'Confirm Exit',
      message: 'Really exit app?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Disagree clicked');
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Exit',
          handler: () => {
            navigator.app.exitApp();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    nav.present(confirm);
  }

  getNav() {
    return this.app.getComponent('nav');
  }
```

### Note:

If you get errors about app not being a property of **navigator**:

1) Add a typings folder to your app root: e.g. **app/typings**

2) Add a file called: **pluginshackyhacky.d.ts**

3) Add for properties you need extended for TypeScript to compile.:

```
interface /*PhoneGapNavigator extends*/ Navigator {
    app: any;
}
```

4) Add the pluginshackyhacky.d.ts to the compile in the **tsconfig.json**:

```
  "files": [
    "app/app.ts",
    "app/typings/pluginshackyhacky.d.ts",
    "app/typings/phonegap.d.ts"
  ]
```

You can see that I've also included the phonegap.d.ts file which includes a lot of missing properties/variables that allows TypeScript to compile without errors.

Hope this helps anyone having this problem.

Cheers.

Comment: can you please help me on this.. there is no app.ts file. is it possible to register this events on app.component.ts file. Can you update this little more clear

Comment: If you see the comment on my blog, I stopped using this ages ago as it was unreliable. I wouldn't suggest trying again until the framework is out of RC stage.

Comment: `this.platform.registerBackButtonAction(()=>{this.closeModal()});` okay I am trying like this. I guess it may work http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/Platform .Thanks for the reply. I added this on each component constructor i'll try this

Answer (score 1):

may be this could help you.

```
 $state.$current.name == "";var backbutton=0;
 $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {

    if (($state.$current.name == "app.intro") ||
        ($state.$current.name == "app.main.home") ||
        ($state.$current.name == "app.account")) {
        if(backbutton==0){
            backbutton++;
            window.plugins.toast.showLongBottom('Press again to exit');
            $timeout(function(){backbutton=0;},3000);
        }else{
            navigator.app.exitApp();
             }
        console.log("one");
    }else if($state.$current.name == "app.welcome.takeControl") {
        console.log("two");
            $state.go("app.main.home");
    }else{
        console.log("three");
            navigator.app.backHistory();
          }
}, 100);
```