# Ion-Slide-Box go back one slide via back button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

In my Ionic app I have a ion-slide-box with 3 slides. I disabled swiping and jump to the next slide via a button which uses `$ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index)`

Now I'm trying to go back one slide with the back button of the mobile phone. So basically with `$ionicHistory.goBack()`

Also, if I go to a new state and come back to the slide-box I want to jump directly to the slide from which I have left.

Does anyone have an idea how I could do this?

Comment: Have you tried with `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (e) {...});`?

Comment: [try using this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34193115/4302328)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to beaver and the_mahasagar!

The solution is using  `$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {})`

Also I used `ng-init=init_function()` to check for the state if I come from the `$ionicHistory.goBack()` to jump directly to the correct slide.

For those interested here the basic code:

```
$scope.currentSlide = 0

$scope.nextSlide = function() {
    $scope.currentSlide++
    $scope.goToSlide($scope.currentSlide)
}

$scope.goToSlide = function(index) {
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.slide(index)
}

$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    if($scope.currentSlide > 0)
        $scope.goToSlide($scope.currentSlide-1)
    else
        $ionicHistory.goBack()
}, 140)

$scope.init_function = function() {
    if(STATE) // a certain state after you jumped out to a new view and back via $ionicHistory.goBack()
        $scope.goToSlide(NUMBER)
}
```

obviously you need to do some checks i.e. if it is the last slide etc.